# Use vim to edit ANY text on Linux

Tags: linux, vim, ubuntu, editing

I come from the Mac world, where I use http://www.hogbaysoftware.com/products/quickcursor to edit text from anywhere in Vim.

Is there anything like that on Linux ? I'm already using "It's All Text" in Firefox, but I'm looking for something broader.

Also, I've looked at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826208/making-vim-ubiquitous), but it's only solutions for software X, and software Y. Any idea ?

Comment: @Evan: I'm a Linux user and I'm not interested in Macs. You don't have to pay; he offers the source on Github.. and its not as simple as opening a file from your file browser. Have you seen the video on the app's homepage?. Personally I can't see the point of it, but I'm not Julien, and maybe I like calico :) .. @Julien: I like the " one-editor " idea, and I often copy text to my favourite editor and then paste it back. That can be done in about 4 keyboard actions, using a very short script. But I'm not sure of the details of what quickcursor does. Does it always paste the entire vim document?

Comment: I'm becoming more interested in it! I tried the FF addon, and it's quite good (using it now :), so +1 for even that reference. I read QuickCursor's pdf https://github.com/jessegrosjean/quickcursor/blob/master/QuickCursor%20User%27s%20Guide.pdf?raw=true. It uses simple copy and paste, but he monitors the source TEXTAREA in a manner which is beyond simple scripting. I think the FF plugin gets it easier, as it only has to deal with text in it own environment (which it has full access to). QuickCursor looks good, but until a Linux equivalent surfaces, its back to Alt+Tab and It's All Text :)

Comment: I don't know of any tool like that in Linux. I would email the guys from quickcursor and ask them to port it. I expect that it will be a mission to make it a universal Linux tool as it seam like it is working with the Mac windows manager and Linux has so many. I would be specific in your request ask for them to port it to gnome or kde which ever you use. I might also try posting on the gnome and kde projects wish lists for a feature like that.

Answer (score 2):

It would depend on what file manager you are using, but most of them you can usually add some sort of right-click menu item to "Open in Vim".

I use [Dolphin](http://dolphin.kde.org/) for [KDE4](http://www.kde.org/). To add menu items (called service menus) you create a .desktop file in your service menus folder. In my system this resides in `/usr/share/kde4/services/ServiceMenus` but it may vary for your system.

Create the file `open_in_vim.desktop` with the following contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
X-SuSE-translate=true
Type=Service
MimeType=all/allfiles
ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin
Actions=openInVim
X-KDE-Priority=TopLevel

[Desktop Action openInVim]
Name=Open in Vim
Icon=gvim
Exec=gvim %u
```

Restart Dolphin (or Konqueror) and you should see this option when you right-click on a file.

If you would also like to be able to open folders in vim, then change the mime type to `all/all`.

If you would prefer to have "Open in Vim" appear under the `Actions` menu then remove the line, `X-KDE-Priority=TopLevel`

Granted, it's not intuitive, but you don't have to pay money in order to do it!

Comment: For KDE5, use `~/.local/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this script: [quicked](http://paste.ubuntu.com/569429/).  I was inspired to have a bash at it, after having tried *It's all Text!*.. (Hey, I'm Australian; the "bash" pun was unavoidable :)

It isn't as slick as *It's all Text!* which is limited to use within Firefox, but it works for (almost) ALL text in (almost) ALL windows ...I'm using Ubuntu 10.04

It should(?) work in other X11 / Gnome environments, but it may not(?).

By default it is set to use `gedit`, and you can choose `gvim` if you prefer...
 ...just change the value of *EDITOR=*

Be sure to read **all** the comments..

It should do the trick until something better comes along...

PS: You must pre-select some text, but there is no need to copy it to the Clipboard.
Just **select** the text and then press whatever shortcut key you've chosen for *`quicked`*

PPS:
In the script's comments I forgot to mention: *`xwininfo`* is in the *`x11-utils`* suite.
...so, to install all the dependencies on Ubuntu/Debianm use the following command

- sudo apt-get install wmctrl xclip xdotool x11-utils zenity

Comment: The linked 'paste' is no longer available.